# Disabling Django Silk for specific URLs

Tags: django, django-silk

I have an API endpoint on which I can upload a photo using a multipart request. When Silk is trying to parse the request, I get a decoding error.

I now want to disable Silk for certain URL endpoints. Is this already possible? If so, how should I configure this? If not, what is the easiest way of temporarily disabling Silk altogether?

Link to Github issue: https://github.com/jazzband/django-silk/issues/292

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **not possible** yet, but you can inherit from the Silk middleware and exclude some views from being silked using [process_view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/middleware/#process-view) django middleware method. E.g. class-based views in django has `view_class` attribute so you can figure out view class in middleware:

```
def process_view(request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
    if view_func.view_class == SomeClassBasedView:
        # ignore it
    else:
        return super().process_view(request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs)
```

The easiest way of temporarily disabling Silk altogether is removing it from middleware list.

Comment: Maybe you should make onr fork in the project and make the option to process urls manually?

Answer (score 2):

An improvement on milad's solution is to set `SILKY_IGNORE_PATHS` to a custom class with a containment method. This allows ignoring urls that include path arguments.

In urls.py:

```
from silk.config import SilkyConfig

urlpatterns = [
    ...
]

class PathMatcher:
    def __init__(self, url_patterns):
        self.url_patterns = url_patterns

    def __contains__(self, item):
        item = item.lstrip('/')
        return any(p.pattern.match(item) for p in self.url_patterns)


SilkyConfig().SILKY_IGNORE_PATHS = PathMatcher(
    urlpatterns[5:10] +  # a subset of the patterns specified in urlpatterns
    [u for u in router.urls if u.name.startswith('analytics-event')] +  # a subset of DRF router urls
    [re_path('^admin/analytics/event/(.*)', lambda: None)]  # hardcoded path
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use django-silk==4.2.0 and it has SILKY_IGNORE_PATHS config that you can set in your django settings